# How to deep clone/copy in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, deep-copy, ef-core-2.0

What I would like to do is duplicate/copy my `School` object and all of its children/associations in EF Core

I have something like the following:

```
var item = await _db.School
.AsNoTracking()
.Include(x => x.Students)
.Include(x => x.Teachers)
.Include(x => x.StudentClasses)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Class)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == schoolId);
```

I have been reading up on deep cloning and it seems that I *should* be able to do just add the entity...so pretty much the next line.

```
await _db.AddAsync(item);
```

Then EF should be smart enough to add that entity as a NEW entity. However, right off the bat I get a conflict that says "the id {schoolId} already exists" and will not insert. Even if I reset the Id of the new item I am trying to add, I still get conflicts with the Ids of the associations/children of the school iteam.

Is anyone familiar with this and what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: From your line `item.Id == Guid.NewGuid()` you are not setting the property, you are checking for equality.  I'm assuming  you aren't actually setting the property to a different value prior to saving.  Show more of the code you are running so we can better help, but at first glance this looks to be the issue.

Comment: Sorry what I'm trying to do is just clone my item object. I will try to re-word my question!

Comment: Actually this is considered as improvement in EF Core 2. Even if you call `Add`, the entities with non default PKs (e.g. 0, `Guid.Empty` etc.) will be considered as existing. I'm afraid "deep cloning" is not EF Core target. See [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities).

Comment: That's what I was hoping not to hear :)

Comment: You can play with `TrackGraph` method to simulate forced `Add`. Inside the callback you have to set the entity PK to `default(Guid)` and state to `Added`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem too, but in my case EF core was throwing exception "the id already exists".
Following the answer of @Irikos so I have created method which clones my objects.

Here's example

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Templates { get; set; }

    public Parent Clone()
    {
        var output = new Parent() { SomeProperty = SomeProperty };

        CloneTemplates(output);

        return output;
    }

    private void CloneTemplates(Parent parentTo, Child oldTemplate = null, Child newTemplate = null)
    {
        //find old related Child elements
        var templates = Templates.Where(c => c.Template == oldTemplate);

        foreach (var template in templates)
        {
            var newEntity = new Child()
            {
                SomeChildProperty = template.SomeChildProperty,
                Template = newTemplate,
                Parent = parentTo
            };

            //find recursivly all related Child elements
            CloneTemplates(parentTo, template, newEntity);

            parentTo.Templates.Add(newEntity);
        }
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int? TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Template { get; set; }
    public string SomeChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I just call `DbContext.Parents.Add(newEntity)` and `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

That worked for me. Maybe this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but in my case, ef core was smart enough save them as new entities even with existing id. However, before realising that, I just made a copy constructor for all the items, created a local task variable containing only the desired properties and returned the copy.

[Remove certain properties from object upon query EF Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571232/remove-certain-properties-from-object-upon-query-ef-core-2-1/52577115#52577115)