# Remove certain properties from object upon query EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to null or remove the ID entirely of all the queried IsoDataTables before returning them to frontend. The idea is that it should behave (in this case) as a template and I don't want it returning the id's back to me, nor do I want them to be removed in the frontend.

```
var applicationType = await _context.ApplicationType
                                    .Include(m => m.IsoTableData)
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

if (applicationType == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

if (applicationType.IsoTableData != null)
{
    foreach (IsoTableData isoTableData in applicationType.IsoTableData)
    {
        // error since it a not nullable primary key
        isoTableData.Id = null;
    }
}

return Ok(applicationType);
```

I have found a workaround in which I duplicate the objects and return them (without saving to DB) but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: map them to instances of a new class, that does not have the property in question?

Comment: That's what I did. Was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I ended up creating a copy constructor, selecting the fields I want to and returned to local task variable. (not shown in the question code)

Comment: @Irikos: mapping them to another object is an enabler for *separation of layers*.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was create a copy constructor (or basically, a new instance of an object) with the desired fields; I chose a copy constructor as this logic is recurent in other places as well. Another similar solution is creating a DTO object, but I don't need it here. Any improvements?

```
//in IsoFileApplicationType.cs
public IsoFileApplicationType(IsoFileApplicationType isoFileApplicationType)
{
    Id = null
    FullName = isoFileApplicationType.FullName;
    Name = isoFileApplicationType.Name;
    (...)


    foreach (IsoTableData isoTableData in isoFileApplicationType.IsoTableData)
    {
        IsoTableData.Add(IsoTableData(isoTableData));
    }
}

//in IsoTableData.cs
public IsoTableData(IsoTableData isoTableData)
{
    Id = null;
    Data = isoTableData.Name;
    Age = isoTableData.Age;
    (...)
}

// in CRUD controller
var applicationType = await _context.ApplicationType
                                   .Include(m => m.IsoTableData)
                                   .AsNoTracking()
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

if (applicationType == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}
IsoFileApplicationType newIsoFileApplicationType = IsoFileApplicationType(applicationType);
return Ok(newIsoFileApplicationType);
```

Comment: You don't mention it (unless its implied by using your result set as a template), but you do realize you cannot update or delete existing entities this way.  As templates containing a subset of fields, I'd use DTO objects to keep data/business logic separate from UI concerns.  Server-side WebAPI with a separate client comes to mind.